# Vue push() is overwriting previous data in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am passing data from a child component (Form) to its parent component (App).The data is being passed just fine but when I need to add the data to the array created in the App component,all previous elements in the array are overwritten and the same element appears in each position.

```
<template>
  <Form :addPC="getPC" />
</template>

<script>
import Form from './components/Form.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components:{
    Form,
  },
  methods:{
    getPC(pc)
    {
      var PC = {}
      PC = pc
      this.PCs.push(PC)
      console.log(this.PCs)
    }
  },
  data(){
      return{
        PCs:[]
      }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `Form` component? It largely depends on how it is using the function given for the `addPC` prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are saving the same object reference in your "pcs" array, so any changes to your array are reflected in all elements. Try the following solution:

```
getPC(pc) {
    // Create a new object using the spread operator
    const newPC = { ...pc };
    this.PCs.push(newPC);
    console.log(this.PCs);
  }
```